# How to resolve graphql syntax erros gatsby.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to run the following graphql query but the terminal is saying I have syntax errors in my code:

```
export const query = graphql`

    query allAirtableLinked(filter: { table: { eq: "Published" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          data {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }

`
```

Terminal declares a syntax error

```
  Error: BabelPluginGraphQL: GraphQL syntax error in query:
    query allAirtableLinked(filter: {table: {eq: "Published"}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          data {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  message:
  Syntax Error GraphQL request (4:27) Expected $, found Name "filter"
  3:
  4:   query allAirtableLinked(filter: {table: {eq: "Published"}}) {
                               ^
  5:     edges {
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing arguments to the GraphQL `query` object and not the query field.

Try something like this:

```
query allAirtableLinked($filter: { table: { eq: "Published" } }) {
  allAirtableLinked(filter: $filter) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        data {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. Still getting a syntax error:
Syntax Error GraphQL request (2:34) Expected Name, found {

1:
2: query allAirtableLinked($filter: { table: { eq: "Published" } }) {
                                    ^
3:   allAirtableLinked(filter: $filter) {